# Space of linear injections between Hilbert spaces must be one-dimensional.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H,K$ be Hilbert spaces and consider a vector subspace $X \le B(H,K)$ such that every $0 \ne x \in X$ is an injection. Do we have $\dim(X) \le 1?$

Attempt: My intuition tells me this is true. Suppose to the contrary that $\dim(X) > 1$. Then I hope to explicitly construct $x,y\in B(H,K)$ such that there is $\xi\ne 0$ with $x \xi = y \xi$. Because in that case, $x-y \in X$ would not be injective.

I'm aware of Kadison's transitivity theorem but for that we need $H=K$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  For a really simple example, if $H$ is 1-dimensional, then your condition holds for *all* of $B(H,K)$.

More generally, if you take a bunch of mutually independent subspaces $H_i\subset K$ (i.e. $H_i$ has trivial intersection with $\sum_{j\neq i}H_j$ for each $i$) which are isomorphic to $H$ and pick isomorphisms $f_i:H\to H_i$ for each $i$, then every nontrivial linear combination of the $f_i$ will still be injective.